# Powershell script for checking password criteria

Tags: powershell, passwords

I'm working on a script that creates local accounts, offering users the chance to enter a password twice, which will then be scrutinised against criteria similar to network accounts.
I've put together the script below, which can *almost* do this. It seems to be capable of some of the criteria I'm trying to plug in.

What I'm looking for is to compare the first and confirmation entry and to check what they have entered against the following combinations, reject them if they don't meet the criteria and accept them if they do:

At least 1 x capital letter, at least 1 x special character, at least 1 x number, at least 8 characters - e.g. "Monkeypuzzle1!"

At least 1 x special character, at least 1 x number, at least 8 characters - e.g. "monkeypuzzle1!"

At least 1 x capital letter, 1 x lowercase letter, at least 1 x special character, at least 8 characters - e.g. "Monkeypuzzle!"

At least 1 x capital letter, 1 x lowercase letter, at least 1 x number, at least 8 characters - "Monkeypuzzle1"

What I have so far successfully compares the first entry and the confirm entry and seems to be capable of scrutinising the **1 x cap, 1 x lowercase, 1 x special, 1 x number, 8 characters** criteria and the **1 x cap, 1x lowercase, 1 x number, 8 characters** criteria, but not the other two. I've tried several methods and so far I just can't crack it.

```
while($true)
{
        try
        {
            # Loop until a valid password is entered.

            $Entered_Password_01 = Read-Host "Enter a password: "-AsSecureString
            $Entered_Password_01_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Entered_Password_01))
            Write-Host ""
            $Pass_criteria_01 = (-not(($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text.length -ge 7) -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d')))
            $Pass_criteria_02 = (-not(($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text.length -ge 7) -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '!|@|#|%|^|&|$')))
            $Pass_criteria_03 = (-not(($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text.length -ge 7) -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '!|@|#|%|^|&|$')))
            $Pass_criteria_04 = (-not(($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text.length -ge 7) -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '!|@|#|%|^|&|$')))
            if (        $Pass_criteria_01 -or
                        $Pass_criteria_02 -or
                        $Pass_criteria_03 -or
                        $Pass_criteria_04)
            {throw}
            $Entered_Password_02 = Read-Host "Confirm password: "-AsSecureString
            $Entered_Password_02_text = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Entered_Password_02))
            Write-Host ""
            if ($Entered_Password_01_text -ceq $Entered_Password_02_text) {Write-host "successful test"}
            Else
            {throw}
            break
        }
        catch
        {
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "Invalid Password." -ForegroundColor Red
        }
}
```

I'm basically trying to tell it to sequentially check it against 4 sets of criteria, snag it if it doesn't measure up and let it through if it does.

If anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve this please let me know.

Cheers.

Expansion on **mklement0's** answer, seems to do the job, seems to have passed all the tests I can think of at the moment, had to modify my method of looking for special characters by looking for characters that aren't uppercase, lowercase or numbers. But that count idea was golden!

```
$Entered_Password_01_text = 'Monkeypuzzle1!' # Experiment with different values here.
$Special_Chars = "[^a-zA-Z0-9]" #check for special characters, by looking for not regular characters or numbers.
$Password_Criteria = (
  (
                (($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d')),                                                         # At least 1 x lowercase, at least 1 x uppercase, at least 1 x number and 8 characters.
                (($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch $Special_Chars)),                                                  # At least 1 x lowercase, at least 1 x number, at least 1 x special characters and 8 characters.
                (($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch $Special_Chars)),                                              # At least 1 x lowercase, at least 1 x uppercase, at least 1 x special characters and 8 characters.
                (($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch $Special_Chars)),                                                  # At least 1 x uppercase, at least 1 x number, at least 1 x special characters and 8 characters.
                (($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[a-z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '\d') -and ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch $Special_Chars))  # At least 1 x lowercase, at least 1 x uppercase, at least 1 x number, at least 1 x special characters and 8 characters.
  ) -eq $true
).Count

$Password_Complexity_Validated = $Entered_Password_01_text.Length -ge 8 -and $Password_Criteria -ge 1

if (-not $Password_Complexity_Validated) { Write-host  'Invalid password.' -ForegroundColor Red
}Else{
Write-host 'Password is valid.'-ForegroundColor Green }
```

Comment: `if ($Entered_Password_01_text -match "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$") { "Passed!" }` would this work for your needs?

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking at this. Unfortunately I couldn't get this to parse at all.

Comment: What do you mean by, "*couldn't get this to parse at all*"? Did it fail?

Comment: Ok,  I fleshed it out a bit, I can get some passwords matching the criteria to pass through, but not all. **Monkeypuzzle1** and **Monkeypuzzle!** for example won't go through.

`$Entered_Password_01_text = 'Monkeypuzzle1'`
           
`if ($Entered_Password_01_text -match "^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d@$!%*?&]{8,}$"){`
`Write-Host "passed"}`
`Else{`
`Write-Host "not passed"}`

Comment: `1234567!` still matches "At least 1 x special character, at least 1 x number, at least 8 characters" - are you conflating _characters_ with _letters_?

Comment: Also: you probably mean _digit_, not number. (_Decimal_ digit, to be more precise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Focusing just on the core logic, try the following:

```
$Entered_Password_01_text = 'foooooo1!' # Experiment with different values here.

$numCriteriaMet = (
  (
    ($Entered_Password_01_text -cmatch '[A-Z]'),     # at least 1 uppercase letter
    ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '[!@#%^&$]'),  # at least 1 special char.
    ($Entered_Password_01_text -match '[0-9]')       # at least 1 digit
  ) -eq $true
).Count

# A password is valid if it is at least 8 chars. long
# and meets at least 2 of the 3 criteria above.
$validOverall = $Entered_Password_01_text.Length -ge 8 -and $numCriteriaMet -ge 2

if (-not $validOverall) { throw 'Invalid password.' }

Write-Verbose -Verbose 'Password is valid.'
```

Comment: Hi, this is nice, but unfortunately it does let through passwords like 1234567! I do like the approach though.

Comment: I guess I could have described it better, but frankly it's kind of hard to describe, which is why I included examples. I'm basically looking to emulate the default AD complexity requirements, with the obvious exceptions of 24 password history and no more than no more than two symbols from the user’s account name or display name.

Comment: I merged your idea and mine and I think it does the job, that count idea was just what I needed to present lines of criteria and funnel the variable through an appropriate one. Cheers for your help.

Comment: @VihaanReyansh, I'm glad to hear my answer helped, but instead of editing a solution into your _question_, you should post it as an _answer_. That said, if the answer addresses requirements not stated in the question, that will cause confusion - leaving aside that you're not properly giving credit to the answer that does address your question _as asked_.